# Primary expression before Double which is in my Array?

Tags: c++, arrays

IT keep asking me for a primary expression before Double which is in my int Array and i dont know what to do. i have midterms tomorrow ugh this hurts my brain. All other input would be helpful thanks :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void get_input(double array[50], int& sizearray1)
{
    cout << "How many doubles do you wish to add?" << endl;
    cin >> sizearray1;
    while(sizearray1 < 1 || sizearray1 > 50) {
        cout << "Error: That is an invalid number! You must enter a value between 1 and 50.\nHow many doubles do you wish to add?" << endl;
        cin >> sizearray1;
    }
    for(int n=1;n<sizearray1;n++){
        cout << "Enter Double " << n << endl;
        cin >> array[n];
    }
}

double calcSum(double array[50],int sizearray1)
{
    int sum
cout << "The sum is ";
for(n=1,n<sizearray1,n++){
    sum += array[n]
}
cout << sum << endl;
}


void printArray(double c[],int sizearray1)
{
    cout << "The array contains:\n";

    for(int n=1;n<sizearray1;n++){
            cout << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed  << c[n] << "       ";
    }
    calcSum(double array[50],int sizearray1);
}


int main()
{
    double array1[50];
    int sizearray1 = 0;
    get_input(double array[50],int sizearray1);
    printArray(double array[50],int sizearray1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'm going to start off with some errors, as THIS code can't compile. No way.
You're missing a semicolon at `int sum` line 21. Your for loop at line 23 has commas instead of semicolons. You're using a undefined variable `n = 1` in the same loop, you have to declare it before doing so `for(n=1,n<sizearray1,n++)`. Again in the same for loop at line 24 you forgot another semicolon `sum += array[n]`.

Back to your question:
You can't give a function a type parameter, you would actually try to declare a variable there. Also please don't declare a function like this `double calcSum (double array[50], int sizearray1)` as this is really not what you want... use this instead `double calcSum (double array[/*Nothing here*/], int sizearray1)`.

Please check your whole code and fix all errors. This is a fix of me. Of course it doesn't work, your code is a bit to messy, check all the functions and give them the right parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void get_input (double array[], int& sizearray1)
{
    cout << "How many doubles do you wish to add?" << endl;
    cin >> sizearray1;
    while (sizearray1 < 1 || sizearray1 > 50)
    {
        cout << "Error: That is an invalid number! You must enter a value between 1 and 50.\nHow many doubles do you wish to add?" << endl;
        cin >> sizearray1;
    }
    for (int n = 1; n < sizearray1; n++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Double " << n << endl;
        cin >> array[n];
    }
}

double calcSum (double array[], int sizearray1)
{
    int sum;
    cout << "The sum is ";
    for (int n = 1; n < sizearray1; n++)
    {
        sum += array[n];
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}


void printArray (double c[], int sizearray1)
{
    cout << "The array contains:\n";

    for (int n = 1; n < sizearray1; n++)
    {
        cout << setprecision(2) << showpoint << fixed  << c[n] << "       ";
    }
    calcSum (array[50], sizearray1); //This still can't work, the variable "array" has not been declared
}


int main()
{
    double array1[50];
    int sizearray1 = 0;
    get_input (array[50], sizearray1); //Again "array" has not been declared
    printArray (array[50], sizearray1); //Again "array" has not been declared
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling a function don`t include the type like :

```
calcSum(double array[50],int sizearray1);
```

But simply use the variable names :

```
calcSum(array[50],sizearray1);
```

same with your `get_input()` and `printArray()` functions.

And in your `printArray()` function, I think you are recieving the passed array into the variable `c`. So it should be :

```
calcSum(c[50],sizearray1);
```

And I think you are trying to pass the whole array, then you just have to use the arrayname:

```
calcSum(c,sizearray1);
```

`c[50]` will only pass the element at 50th position in the array.

Comment: I think they don't mean to pass `array[50]`, but rather the whole array.

Comment: @juanchopanza edited my answer. Missed that one out.